# WCF REST Proxy using ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy WCF service over a WCF service using ChannelFactory.

I have defined the following interface for the WCF service to call. It has a generic GetResource method that writes directly into HttpContext the response byte[] and sets it's content type based on the type of the resource.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "getResource/?resourceKey={resourceKey}")]
  void GetResource(string resourceKey);
}
```

Proxy implementation for GetResource:

```
public void GetResource(string resourceKey)
{
   var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(GetCustomBinding(), new   EndpointAddress('https://test.com/mytest.svc'));
   channel.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
   var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
  using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)channel))
  {
    channel.GetResource(resourceKey);
  }

}



private static Binding GetCustomBinding()
        {
            var binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000,
                MaxBufferSize = 20000000,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000,
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
            };

            binding.ContentTypeMapper = new JsonMapper();

            return binding;

        }

private class JsonMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {

                return WebContentFormat.Json;

        }
    }
```

The problem that I have is that when I'm calling the proxy at this endpoint, proxy.svc/GetResource?resourceKey="text.css" it returns the right content type but no actual content, ContentLength=0.

How should I handle Response Body forwarding? How do I read the response body? I tried using WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse but it doesn't give me the response body as well.

Comment: service that I'm calling through the channel writes the bytes directly in the response body

Comment: @BogdanM. ok, but *why*? Why not `return` something?

Comment: It is used this way : <img src="proxy.svc/GetResource?resourceKey='test.jpg'"> with different content types, similar for css or other resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are attempting to use WCF in a way that it is not intended. A void method will return nothing. In theory, you can intercept this by adding an inspection behaviour, but not even sure that would work.

I have (potentially) similar code which loads file from a database and returns them, but that will `return` the content.

```
 var file = ServiceUtilities.FileManager.GetFile(id);


            if (file != null)
            {
                var fcr = new FileContentResult(file.Content, file.MimeType);
                return fcr;
            }
```

Perhaps you should revisit your intended approach.

Comment: I need a solution for this without changing a lot of code on the client side...politics.

Comment: marked as accepted, we end up changing the interface which is the right thing to do. thanks